# Using Sagemath to check if a ring is integrally closed

Tags: commutative-algebra, sagemath

I was playing around in Sage earlier today, and I can't seem to figure out how to check whether the localization of an order in a number field is integrally closed. I'm fairly new to Sage, so I'm a little confused as to what the issue is. My code is below:

```
K.<i> = NumberField(x^2 + 1)
O = K.order(2*i)
Op = O.localization(2 + 2*i)
Op.is_integrally_closed()
```

This gives me a `NotImplementedError` saying that `IntegerModRing_generic_with_category` object has no attribute `is_integrally_closed`. I can see, however, that the object `Op` has type `sage.rings.localization.Localization_with_category`. I can't find the class `sage.rings.localization.Localization_with_category` in the documentation, but in `sage.rings.localization`, the base is listed as `sage.rings.ring.IntegralDomain`, which has a method `is_integrally_closed()` listed.

I know how to check the math here - I'm just trying to figure out how to get Sage to check this for me, and better understand how Sage categories, parents, classes, etc. work.

P.S. I am running Sage 9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `is_integrally_closed` for integral domains is what is raising this error: see https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings/sage/rings/ring.html#sage.rings.ring.IntegralDomain.is_integrally_closed. Note that if you instead do `O.is_integrally_closed()`, it returns `False`: it can apparently check orders, but not rings in this generality.

Comment: Huh, ok thanks!